# Anchor tag not clickable in outlook

Tags: html, outlook

So I have a SMTP server to send emails. I want to include some hyperlinks in the email. Right now I am constructing the hyperlinks like this:

```
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

However, when I received it from outlook. The link is not displayed as expected and is not clickable. When I do an inspect element, I am getting:

```
<body>
<ul>
  <li>[/https://google.com]https://google.com</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable HTML for the body of the Mail message.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how do I enable it? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will add an answer but I deal in PHP.

Answer (score -2):

```html
We will use the message parameter(a big string we pass to the mail function with the body of our email).

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

Now using PHP mail():-

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Just use this according to your needs.
```

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I already included the <html> tag when I construct the email. So I don't think that's the reason why the anchor tag is not working.

Comment: this answer doesn't answer the users question at all. For me, including <a href="https://google.com">link text</a> will work on almost all email platforms. However, the link is not clickable on Windows laptops using the Outlook email client. It is not sending the email itself, it is client compatibility. Answer that and I will +1.